# Referring to routes in routes.rb rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a pages controller as well as views. In the views/pages folder, I have the following views:

```
home.html.erb
activities.html.erb
```

If I add the following in my config/routes.rb:

```
resources :pages do
  resources :home
  resources: activities
end
```

Will I be able to refer to the paths for the home and activities pages as follows:

```
pages_home_path
pages_activities_path
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in the route definition, it should be:

```
resources :pages do
  resources :home
  resources :activities
end
```

You can verify what the named routes are by running `bundle exec rake routes`. This is the output for this definition:

```
              Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                               Controller#Action
     page_home_index GET    /pages/:page_id/home(.:format)                            home#index
                     POST   /pages/:page_id/home(.:format)                            home#create
       new_page_home GET    /pages/:page_id/home/new(.:format)                        home#new
      edit_page_home GET    /pages/:page_id/home/:id/edit(.:format)                   home#edit
           page_home GET    /pages/:page_id/home/:id(.:format)                        home#show
                     PATCH  /pages/:page_id/home/:id(.:format)                        home#update
                     PUT    /pages/:page_id/home/:id(.:format)                        home#update
                     DELETE /pages/:page_id/home/:id(.:format)                        home#destroy
     page_activities GET    /pages/:page_id/activities(.:format)                      activities#index
                     POST   /pages/:page_id/activities(.:format)                      activities#create
   new_page_activity GET    /pages/:page_id/activities/new(.:format)                  activities#new
  edit_page_activity GET    /pages/:page_id/activities/:id/edit(.:format)             activities#edit
       page_activity GET    /pages/:page_id/activities/:id(.:format)                  activities#show
                     PATCH  /pages/:page_id/activities/:id(.:format)                  activities#update
                     PUT    /pages/:page_id/activities/:id(.:format)                  activities#update
                     DELETE /pages/:page_id/activities/:id(.:format)                  activities#destroy
               pages GET    /pages(.:format)                                          pages#index
                     POST   /pages(.:format)                                          pages#create
            new_page GET    /pages/new(.:format)                                      pages#new
           edit_page GET    /pages/:id/edit(.:format)                                 pages#edit
                page GET    /pages/:id(.:format)                                      pages#show
                     PATCH  /pages/:id(.:format)                                      pages#update
                     PUT    /pages/:id(.:format)                                      pages#update
                     DELETE /pages/:id(.:format)                                      pages#destroy
```

You can then use these prefixes as `page_activity_path` or `page_activity_url`.